# My "Total Number' Will iterate different number amounts, even though I used --

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a shopping cart and it displays how many items are in the cart. It will go up by one if you press 'Add to cart' and will go down by one when you press 'remove'. I have a bug that does this.. When I press each 'remove' button it will take away different types of amounts from the 'total number' depending on which 'remove' button I click, and I want each button to only take away one number on each click event

CODE:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>E-Commerce Website</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/fonts/fontawesome-free-5.3.1-web/css/all.css"><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-AYmEC3Yw5cVb3ZcuHtOA93w35dYTsvhLPVnYs9eStHfGJvOvKxVfELGroGkvsg+p" crossorigin="anonymous"/>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="app.js"async></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="p1">
            <div class="topnavcont">
                <ul class="topleftnav">
                <li class="topnavlink">Home</li>
                <li class="topnavlink">Shop</li>
            </ul>
            <h1 class="topnavtitle">The Store</h1>
            <div class="navcartcontainer">
                <h3 class="totalnumber">0</h3>
                <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart" id="cartbtn"></i>
            </div>
            </div>

            <img src="clark-street-mercantile-vC-GqGbakJo-unsplash.jpg" alt="" class="bgimg">
            <div class="overlay"></div>
            <div class="cartbody">
                <i class="fal fa-times" id="closeicon"></i>
                <h2 class="carttitle">Shopping Cart</h2>
                <ul class="cartitems">
                    <!-- <div><li class="cartitem"><span class="itemtitle">Shirt1</span><span class="itemprice">$8.99</span><input type="number"class="qinput"id="qinput"><button class="removebtn">Remove</button></li></div>
                    <div><li class="cartitem"><span class="itemtitle">Shirt2</span><span class="itemprice">$8.99</span><input type="number"class="qinput"id="qinput"><button class="removebtn">Remove</button></li></div>
                    <div><li class="cartitem"><span class="itemtitle">Shirt3</span><span class="itemprice">$8.99</span><input type="number"class="qinput"id="qinput"><button class="removebtn">Remove</button></li></div> -->
                </ul>
                <div class="carttotal">Total: <span id='actualprice'> $64.66</span></div>
                
            </div>
        </div>

<div class="p2">
    <h1 class="p2title">My Shop</h1>
    <div class="itemcontainer">
<div class="item">
    <img src="clark-street-mercantile-vC-GqGbakJo-unsplash.jpg" alt="" class="item-img">
    <h1 class="item-title">Shirt1</h1>
    <h3 class="itemprice">$8.99</h3>
    <!-- <a href="#" class="atcbtn">Add To Cart</a> -->
    <button class="atcbtn">Add To Cart</button>
</div>

<div class="item">
    <img src="clark-street-mercantile-vC-GqGbakJo-unsplash.jpg" alt="" class="item-img">
    <h1 class="item-title">Shirt2</h1>
    <h3 class="itemprice">$8.99</h3>
    <!-- <a href="#" class="atcbtn">Add To Cart</a> -->
    <button class="atcbtn">Add To Cart</button>
</div>

<div class="item">
    <img src="clark-street-mercantile-vC-GqGbakJo-unsplash.jpg" alt="" class="item-img">
    <h1 class="item-title">Shirt3</h1>
    <h3 class="itemprice">$8.99</h3>
    <!-- <a href="#" class="atcbtn">Add To Cart</a> -->
    <button class="atcbtn">Add To Cart</button>
</div>

</div>
    <div class="itemcontainer2">
<div class="item">
    <img src="clark-street-mercantile-vC-GqGbakJo-unsplash.jpg" alt="" class="item-img">
    <h1 class="item-title">Shirt4</h1>
    <h3 class="itemprice">$8.99</h3>
    <!-- <a href="#" class="atcbtn">Add To Cart</a> -->
    <button class="atcbtn">Add To Cart</button>
</div>

<div class="item">
    <img src="clark-street-mercantile-vC-GqGbakJo-unsplash.jpg" alt="" class="item-img">
    <h1 class="item-title">Shirt5</h1>
    <h3 class="itemprice">$8.99</h3>
    <!-- <a href="#" class="atcbtn">Add To Cart</a> -->
    <button class="atcbtn">Add To Cart</button>
</div>

<div class="item">
    <img src="clark-street-mercantile-vC-GqGbakJo-unsplash.jpg" alt="" class="item-img">
    <h1 class="item-title">Shirt6</h1>
    <h3 class="itemprice">$8.99</h3>
    <!-- <a href="#" class="atcbtn">Add To Cart</a> -->
    <button class="atcbtn">Add To Cart</button>
</div>

</div>

</div>


    </div>
  
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar{
    display: none;
}
.wrapper{
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
.topnavcont{
    padding: 1em 0em;
    align-items: center;
    height: 10vh;
    width: 100vw;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.10) 0px 3px 6px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.20) 0px 3px 6px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 5;
}


.topleftnav{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 10%;
    margin-left: -3%;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.topleftnav li{
    cursor: pointer;
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 1.05rem;
    transition: 0.3s ease;
    border-bottom: transparent solid 2px;
}
.topleftnav li:hover{
    border-bottom: black solid 2px;
    transform: scale(1.1);
}
.topnavtitle{
    margin-right: 2.5%;
}
.navcartcontainer{
    display: flex;
    margin-right: -1%;
    
}
.topnavcont .totalnumber{
    color: black;
    padding: 0.2em 0.4em;
    border-radius: 50%;
    font-size: 1.25rem;
    height: fit-content;
    /* cursor: pointer; */
    font-weight: bold;
}

.topnavcont i{
    font-size: 2rem; 
    margin-left: 0.3em;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.4s ease;
    
}
.topnavcont i:hover{
    transform: scale(1.15);
}
.p1{
    height: 100vh;
    position: relative;
}
.p1 img{
    object-fit: cover;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
}
.p1 .overlay::after{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 10vh;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: black;
    opacity: 0.4;
    height: 90vh;
    width: 100%;
}

.cartbody{
    background-color: white;
    position: fixed;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 25vw;
    top: 10%;
    left: 75%;
    z-index: 2100;
    overflow-y: auto;
    transform: translateX(100%);
    transition: 0.6s ease;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0) 0px 0px 0px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.30) 0px 3px 6px;

}
.carttotal{
    font-size: 2rem;
    color: rgb(22, 113, 119);
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-top: 1.5em;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 3em;
}
.cartbody i{
    font-size: 2.2rem;
    margin-left: 0.4em;
    margin-top: 0.2em;
    color: black;
    font-weight: 200;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.3s ease;
}
.cartbody i:hover{
    transform: scale(1.15);
}
.cartbody input{
    width: 2.2rem;
    height: auto;
}
.cartbodyactive{
    transform: translateX(0%);
    transform: scale(1);
    background-color: white;
}
.carttitle{
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 1em;
    margin-bottom: 2em;
}
.cartitem{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
}
.cartitem .itemtitle{
    font-size: 1.2rem;
}
.cartitems{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    row-gap: 3em;
    overflow-y: auto;
    list-style: none;
    padding-left: 0.5em;
}
.removebtn{
    background-color: red;
    color: black;
    font-weight: bold;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    padding: 0.5em 1em;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.p2{
    height: 160vh;
    position: relative;
}
.p2title{
    color: black;
    padding-top: 2.5em;
    margin-left: 7%;
}
.p2 img{
    height: 200px;
    width: 300px;
}
.itemcontainer{
    margin-top: 6em;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
.itemcontainer2{
    margin-top: 6em;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
.item{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 355px;
    justify-content: space-around;
}

.atcbtn{
    background-color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    width: 40%;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: black solid 2px;
    padding: 0.8em 0.5em;
    transition: 0.4s ease;
}
.atcbtn:hover{
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

JAVSCRIPT:

```
let TotalNumber = document.querySelector('.totalnumber');
const Atc = document.getElementsByClassName('atcbtn');
const cartbtn = document.getElementById('cartbtn')
const closeicon = document.getElementById('closeicon')
const cartbody = document.querySelector('.cartbody')
const removebtn = document.getElementsByClassName('removebtn')
const carttotal = document.querySelector('.carttotal')




cartbtn.addEventListener('click', function(){
    cartbody.classList.toggle('cartbodyactive')
})

closeicon.addEventListener('click', function(){
    cartbody.classList.remove('cartbodyactive')
})


function InputToDefault(){

    let   qinput = document.getElementsByClassName('qinput')
    for(let i = 0; i < qinput.length; i++){
    qinput[i].value= 1;
}
}

InputToDefault()


function RemoveItem(){



    for (i = 0; i < removebtn.length; i++){
        let rbutton = removebtn[i];
        rbutton.addEventListener("click", function (){ 



            //HERRE IS THE ISSUE.... HERE IS THE ISSUE...
            let TotalNumbervalue = TotalNumber.innerText 
        if(TotalNumbervalue > 0){
            // console.log(TotalNumbervalue)
            TotalNumber.innerText--
        }
            


            rbutton.parentElement.parentElement.remove()
            
        })
    }
}
    RemoveItem()




function AddItemtoCart(){




for (i = 0; i < Atc.length; i++){

    let button = Atc[i];
    button.addEventListener("click", function (){
        let TotalNumbervalue = TotalNumber.innerHTML 
        if(TotalNumbervalue > -1){
            
            TotalNumber.innerHTML++
        }


        let price = document.getElementById('actualprice')
        let pricenum = price.innerText
        console.log(pricenum)





        let shopitem = button.parentElement
        let shoptitle = shopitem.getElementsByClassName('item-title')[0].innerText
        let shopprice = shopitem.getElementsByClassName('itemprice')[0].innerText
        let cartrow = document.createElement('div')
        let cartitems = document.getElementsByClassName('cartitems')[0]
        let cartrowcontent = `<li class="cartitem"><span class="itemtitle">${shoptitle}</span><span class="itemprice">${shopprice}</span><input type="number" class="qinput"id="qinput"><button class="removebtn">Remove</button></li>`
        cartrow.innerHTML = cartrowcontent
        cartitems.append(cartrow)

        
        qinput.value = 1
        InputToDefault()
        
        RemoveItem()
        
    })
}

}


AddItemtoCart()
```

Comment: `innerText` is always a string.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't go through the rest of your code, but the way you're creating the Remove item event listeners doesn't really make sense. Why call a function when you just need run through the loop. The reason why you're not getting the result you expect is because the `innerText` is a string and you can't do math on strings. Instead, convert it to a number by putting a `+` in front  of it.

```
for (i = 0; i < removebtn.length; i++) {
    let rbutton = removebtn[i];
    rbutton.addEventListener("click", function() {
      let TotalNumbervalue = +TotalNumber.innerText.trim()
      if (TotalNumbervalue > 0) {
        TotalNumber.innerText--
      }
      rbutton.parentElement.parentElement.remove()
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

`removeItem()` loops through all remove button elements and adds a `click` listener that deletes the parent. You call this everytime a new item is added, which means eventually multiple `click` listeners "stack up" and you have multiple `click` listeners removing 1 from the total.

Instead, assign the `click` event listener after appending the element, ensuring only 1 `click` event listener will be applied

```js
let TotalNumber = document.querySelector('.totalnumber');
const Atc = document.getElementsByClassName('atcbtn');
const cartbtn = document.getElementById('cartbtn')
const closeicon = document.getElementById('closeicon')
const cartbody = document.querySelector('.cartbody')
const removebtn = document.getElementsByClassName('removebtn')
const carttotal = document.querySelector('.carttotal')

cartbtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    cartbody.classList.toggle('cartbodyactive')
})

closeicon.addEventListener('click', function() {
    cartbody.classList.remove('cartbodyactive')
})


function InputToDefault() {

    let qinput = document.getElementsByClassName('qinput')
    for (let i = 0; i < qinput.length; i++) {
        qinput[i].value = 1;
    }
}

InputToDefault()

function AddItemtoCart() {
    for (i = 0; i < Atc.length; i++) {

        let button = Atc[i];
        button.addEventListener("click", function() {
            let TotalNumbervalue = TotalNumber.innerHTML
            if (TotalNumbervalue > -1) {

                TotalNumber.innerHTML++
            }


            let price = document.getElementById('actualprice')
            let pricenum = price.innerText
            console.log(pricenum)




            let shopitem = button.parentElement
            let shoptitle = shopitem.getElementsByClassName('item-title')[0].innerText
            let shopprice = shopitem.getElementsByClassName('itemprice')[0].innerText
            let cartrow = document.createElement('div')
            let cartitems = document.getElementsByClassName('cartitems')[0]
            let cartrowcontent = `<li class="cartitem"><span class="itemtitle">${shoptitle}</span><span class="itemprice">${shopprice}</span><input type="number" class="qinput"id="qinput"><button class="removebtn">Remove</button></li>`
            cartrow.innerHTML = cartrowcontent;
            cartitems.append(cartrow)
            cartitems.lastChild.querySelector('.removebtn').addEventListener("click", function() {
                let TotalNumbervalue = +TotalNumber.innerText;
                console.log(TotalNumbervalue);
                if (TotalNumbervalue > 0) {
                    TotalNumber.innerText--
                }
                this.parentElement.parentElement.remove()
            })

            qinput.value = 1
            InputToDefault()
        })
    }
}


AddItemtoCart()
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

.wrapper {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.topnavcont {
  padding: 1em 0em;
  align-items: center;
  height: 10vh;
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.10) 0px 3px 6px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.20) 0px 3px 6px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 5;
}

.topleftnav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 10%;
  margin-left: -3%;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.topleftnav li {
  cursor: pointer;
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 1.05rem;
  transition: 0.3s ease;
  border-bottom: transparent solid 2px;
}

.topleftnav li:hover {
  border-bottom: black solid 2px;
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.topnavtitle {
  margin-right: 2.5%;
}

.navcartcontainer {
  display: flex;
  margin-right: -1%;
}

.topnavcont .totalnumber {
  color: black;
  padding: 0.2em 0.4em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  height: fit-content;
  /* cursor: pointer; */
  font-weight: bold;
}

.topnavcont i {
  font-size: 2rem;
  margin-left: 0.3em;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.4s ease;
}

.topnavcont i:hover {
  transform: scale(1.15);
}

.p1 {
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}

.p1 img {
  object-fit: cover;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}

.p1 .overlay::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 10vh;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 0.4;
  height: 90vh;
  width: 100%;
}

.cartbody {
  background-color: white;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 25vw;
  top: 10%;
  left: 75%;
  z-index: 2100;
  overflow-y: auto;
  transform: translateX(100%);
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0) 0px 0px 0px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.30) 0px 3px 6px;
}

.carttotal {
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: rgb(22, 113, 119);
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-top: 1.5em;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 3em;
}

.cartbody i {
  font-size: 2.2rem;
  margin-left: 0.4em;
  margin-top: 0.2em;
  color: black;
  font-weight: 200;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s ease;
}

.cartbody i:hover {
  transform: scale(1.15);
}

.cartbody input {
  width: 2.2rem;
  height: auto;
}

.cartbodyactive {
  transform: translateX(0%);
  transform: scale(1);
  background-color: white;
}

.carttitle {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 1em;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
}

.cartitem {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.cartitem .itemtitle {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}

.cartitems {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  row-gap: 3em;
  overflow-y: auto;
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0.5em;
}

.removebtn {
  background-color: red;
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  padding: 0.5em 1em;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.p2 {
  height: 160vh;
  position: relative;
}

.p2title {
  color: black;
  padding-top: 2.5em;
  margin-left: 7%;
}

.p2 img {
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
}

.itemcontainer {
  margin-top: 6em;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.itemcontainer2 {
  margin-top: 6em;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 355px;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.atcbtn {
  background-color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  width: 40%;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: black solid 2px;
  padding: 0.8em 0.5em;
  transition: 0.4s ease;
}

.atcbtn:hover {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>E-Commerce Website</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/fonts/fontawesome-free-5.3.1-web/css/all.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-AYmEC3Yw5cVb3ZcuHtOA93w35dYTsvhLPVnYs9eStHfGJvOvKxVfELGroGkvsg+p" crossorigin="anonymous" />

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="app.js" async></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="p1">
      <div class="topnavcont">
        <ul class="topleftnav">
          <li class="topnavlink">Home</li>
          <li class="topnavlink">Shop</li>
        </ul>
        <h1 class="topnavtitle">The Store</h1>
        <div class="navcartcontainer">
          <h3 class="totalnumber">0</h3>
          <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart" id="cartbtn"></i>
        </div>
      </div>

      <img src="clark-street-mercantile-vC-GqGbakJo-unsplash.jpg" alt="" class="bgimg">
      <div class="overlay"></div>
      <div class="cartbody">
        <i class="fal fa-times" id="closeicon"></i>
        <h2 class="carttitle">Shopping Cart</h2>
        <ul class="cartitems">
          <!-- <div><li class="cartitem"><span class="itemtitle">Shirt1</span><span class="itemprice">$8.99</span><input type="number"class="qinput"id="qinput"><button class="removebtn">Remove</button></li></div>
                    <div><li class="cartitem"><span class="itemtitle">Shirt2</span><span class="itemprice">$8.99</span><input type="number"class="qinput"id="qinput"><button class="removebtn">Remove</button></li></div>
                    <div><li class="cartitem"><span class="itemtitle">Shirt3</span><span class="itemprice">$8.99</span><input type="number"class="qinput"id="qinput"><button class="removebtn">Remove</button></li></div> -->
        </ul>
        <div class="carttotal">Total: <span id='actualprice'> $64.66</span></div>

      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="p2">
      <h1 class="p2title">My Shop</h1>
      <div class="itemcontainer">
        <div class="item">
          <img src="clark-street-mercantile-vC-GqGbakJo-unsplash.jpg" alt="" class="item-img">
          <h1 class="item-title">Shirt1</h1>
          <h3 class="itemprice">$8.99</h3>
          <!-- <a href="#" class="atcbtn">Add To Cart</a> -->
          <button class="atcbtn">Add To Cart</button>
        </div>

        <div class="item">
          <img src="clark-street-mercantile-vC-GqGbakJo-unsplash.jpg" alt="" class="item-img">
          <h1 class="item-title">Shirt2</h1>
          <h3 class="itemprice">$8.99</h3>
          <!-- <a href="#" class="atcbtn">Add To Cart</a> -->
          <button class="atcbtn">Add To Cart</button>
        </div>

        <div class="item">
          <img src="clark-street-mercantile-vC-GqGbakJo-unsplash.jpg" alt="" class="item-img">
          <h1 class="item-title">Shirt3</h1>
          <h3 class="itemprice">$8.99</h3>
          <!-- <a href="#" class="atcbtn">Add To Cart</a> -->
          <button class="atcbtn">Add To Cart</button>
        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="itemcontainer2">
        <div class="item">
          <img src="clark-street-mercantile-vC-GqGbakJo-unsplash.jpg" alt="" class="item-img">
          <h1 class="item-title">Shirt4</h1>
          <h3 class="itemprice">$8.99</h3>
          <!-- <a href="#" class="atcbtn">Add To Cart</a> -->
          <button class="atcbtn">Add To Cart</button>
        </div>

        <div class="item">
          <img src="clark-street-mercantile-vC-GqGbakJo-unsplash.jpg" alt="" class="item-img">
          <h1 class="item-title">Shirt5</h1>
          <h3 class="itemprice">$8.99</h3>
          <!-- <a href="#" class="atcbtn">Add To Cart</a> -->
          <button class="atcbtn">Add To Cart</button>
        </div>

        <div class="item">
          <img src="clark-street-mercantile-vC-GqGbakJo-unsplash.jpg" alt="" class="item-img">
          <h1 class="item-title">Shirt6</h1>
          <h3 class="itemprice">$8.99</h3>
          <!-- <a href="#" class="atcbtn">Add To Cart</a> -->
          <button class="atcbtn">Add To Cart</button>
        </div>

      </div>

    </div>


  </div>

</body>

</html>
```